# How to use OpenCV with .Net MAUI to do a camera preview and video recording

Tags: c#, opencv, maui

I am currently trying to use OpenCv with .Net Maui to preview a camera and then once a button is pressed record video. I currently have it where the video will record but then the application will freeze (I suspect due to a threading issue) but no matter what I try I am unable to get the camera preview to work.

```
using (VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0))
        {
            capture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.Fps, 30.0);
            OpenCvSharp.Size dsize = new OpenCvSharp.Size(capture.FrameWidth, capture.FrameHeight);
            //Create video writer using values defines earlier.
            using (VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter("C:/tmp/" + tracking_num + ".avi", four, capture.Fps, dsize, true))
            using (Mat frame = new Mat())
            using (Mat color = new Mat())
            using (Mat canny = new Mat())
            using (Mat image = new Mat()) // Frame image buffer
            {
                using (Mat dst = new Mat())
                {
                    while (recording)
                    {
                        capture.Read(frame);
                        if (frame.Empty())
                            break;
                        //Display video frame as a bitmap to the Video window
                        using (Bitmap bitimg = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame))
                        {
                            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                bitimg.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                                video_display.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
                            }
                        }
                        //Perform write to file for this frame
                        writer.Write(frame);

                        //Magic bullet that waits before running the next frame. Needed for smooth capture
                        if (capture.Fps > 0)
                        {
                            Cv2.WaitKey((1 / (int)capture.Fps) * 1000);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Cv2.WaitKey(1);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you're using C#/.NET, you better use the native APIs provided by .NET, or an ffmpeg wrapper, instead of OpenCV. OpenCV is for *computer vision*. it's not a media library. it certainly isn't as easily "multi-platform" as you appear to require.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you please recommend me any native api?