# Getting error in .net MAUI android project while using OpenCVSharp4

Tags: c#, android, opencv, maui

I want to make an Android app using .net MAUI, which will capture video and extract video frames while capturing video.

For this, I am using OpenCV
.
I have installed

- OpenCvSharp4 v4.8.0.20230708
- OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win v4.8.0.20230708
- OpenCvSharp4.Windows v4.8.0.20230708

I tried extracting frames from previously recorded video in Windows, it's working.
But, while I am trying to test in Android, it's giving
**System.DllNotFoundException: 'OpenCvSharpExtern'**
Exception.

Comment: *OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win* is not compatible with Android and the minimum .NET target version for MAUI is **.NET 6.0** while [*OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win#supportedframeworks-body-tab) targets **.NET 5.0**. I don't think that you can use OpenCvSharp4 with MAUI under Android like that.

Comment: Related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815325/how-to-use-opencv-with-net-maui-to-do-a-camera-preview-and-video-recording